# Authorization header doesn't get sent in cross-origin request

Tags: express, cors, authorization, axios, webpack-dev-server

## Solution at the END.

My server was my problem... Shortly solution, I need to use [express cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

## Original POST:

**First of ALL:**
I have add Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers and i can access the server, but, i can't send data in the Header to the server.

**So:**
I am developing basically with Vue.js (with webpack to hot reload changes) and Express (with nodemon).
So I have 2 separated servers:

- First: backend (server) running at: `http://localhost:3000` with nodemon
- Second: frontend (client) running at: `http://localhost:8080` with webpack-dev-server (to hot reload vuejs changes) it will be develop at single page application.

My server has authotization with passport.js, using jwt token (this articles show how: [authentication vuejs](https://blog.sqreen.io/authentication-best-practices-vue/) and [express passport jwt token](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314)). But not the point, just to explain.

When I make a request (using axios, fetch, doesn't matter) when I send a request to my API from `http://localhost:8080` (**port 8080, webpack**) to the server at `http://localhost:3000/api/products` they **didn't receive** the `Authorization` header.

If, i make a request from the same server, from `http://localhost:3000/index.html` (**port 3000**) to the server at `http://localhost:3000/api/products` they **receive** the `Authorization` header.

I don't know Why!

At the server I implement CORs policy like this:

```
//(...)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, access-control-request-headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, X-Auth-Token, X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept");
  //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  
  //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
//(...)
```

At the client I send the header:

```
  // (...) Imports
  import axios from "axios";

  // (...) other code
  const http = axios.create ({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API,
    timeout: 1000,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  });

  /*   // -- I Have tried this too...
  http.interceptors.request.use (
    function (config) {
      if (token) config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      return config;
    },
    function (error) {
      return Promise.reject (error);
    }
  );      
  */

  http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products', {headers : { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }).then(data => {

// (...) code after
```

When I test at the same server it Works, When in separated server they don't send a header to the server.

Here a gif to show the problem:

[image: gif]

CODE EXAMPLE TO TEST THE PROBLEM: https://github.com/dennnisk/cors_police_response_preflight_does_not_have_http_ok.git

I'm stuck...

---

## **EDIT 1 **:

I Change the code part os axios, adding `withCredentials: true,` as suggested, but got the error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

So, I change the server `app.js` from this:

```
(...)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
(...)
```

To this:

```
(...)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:8080/");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

(...)

And get this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

I think, something is wrong with the server config...

---

## **EDIT 2:**

It was my server. Need to use [express cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)
Posted a answer below...

Comment: If you don’t set 'withCredentials: true' for the axios.get call in your frontend code, the browser won’t send the Authorization header.

Comment: Thanks!, I just tried that, but, don't work. :(.. I Change and got the error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`. I think somenthing is wrong at the server. I tried to change from `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");` to `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:8080");` but doen't work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot add `withCredentials: true` in axios?

```
const myrequests = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  ...
})
```

and after that:

```
myrequests.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products', {headers : { 
  authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
  .then((data) => { 
   // REST OF THE CODE
  })
// (...) code after
```

Comment: Should be fine if you add the `myrequests` configuration in other file and import in main.js instead import axios as it.

Comment: I have tried that. But doesn't work. I think something is wrong at the server. I will edit the post and complement the question with this, and the new error...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to the problem

For some reason that I don't know, my *CORS manual policy* doesn't work correctly.

```
//(...)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, access-control-request-headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, X-Auth-Token, X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept");
  next();
});
//(...)
```

1 - So I eliminate that and install [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) `yarn add cors --save` (or `npm install cors --save`)
2 - Add require for cors:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var cors = require('cors');  ///  <<======= Add here
 var path = require('path');
```

3 - Use cors before my "authentication" method, like:

```
// get authenticated data
app.use('/api/products', cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}), isAutenticated(), function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({id: '1000', text: 'test'});
});
```

That's it. Works fine... finally, after almost 2 days...

I commit the solution at :
https://github.com/dennnisk/cors_police_response_preflight_does_not_have_http_ok

Comment: Yes, probably the problem was the order of setting the middleware for CORS, must be before the authentication method (If is passport it must be one of the last).